# SOAP Request Failure

Tags: c#, soap, soapui

I'm trying to make a SOAP request in C#.  Using SoapUI, I have successfully made the required request, so I basically copied the request string into the LoadXml of the following C# code:

```
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://w8cert.iconnectdata.com:443/FleetCreditWS/services/FleetCreditWS0200");
    webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";

    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();

    soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:main=""http://fleetCredit02.comdata.com/maintenance/"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"">
        <soapenv:Header>
            <wsse:Security>
                <wsse:UsernameToken>
                    <wsse:Username>{MyUserName}</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password>{MyPassword}</wsse:Password>
                    </wsse:UsernameToken>
            </wsse:Security>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <main:ProprietaryIntradayRequest>
                    <startDate>2018-02-06</startDate>
                    <maskCardFlag>false</maskCardFlag>
                </main:ProprietaryIntradayRequest>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>");


    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
    }

    WebResponse response; 

    try
    {

        using (response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream());

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    }
```

This code throws the ever-fun (500) Internal Server Error on the "using (response = webRequest.GetResponse())" line.  I even tried to capture the web exception response, but get the same 500 error.

Can anyone see something I'm missing that would cause the same request to work in SoapUI, but fail in C#?

Comment: _No one_ can see an HTTP 500 error from the client. Your server's administrator have to tell you the error details.

Comment: BTW: horrible error handling with this `try..catch` that ignores the caught exception.

Comment: In addition: Why not use a WSDL-auto-generated proxy that Visual Studio/wsdl.exe generates for you?

Comment: @UweKeim Please don't. The auto-generated proxy from the WSDL creates a lot of trash in your code. Using transparent proxy is much more elegant and easy to maintain

Comment: @Stormhashe What is "transparent proxy"?

Comment: @UweKeim I know the error handling is very incomplete.  That part is only there so I could attempt to see if the exception response had any further information.  This app is nothing but a proof of concept, so all I need to do is get the response successfully.